# How to make banner

Tags: vue.js, shopify, liquid

Here is the code that works but I need to make it efficient, as you can see to meet the condition I repeat the div after  to check if the condiotion is met or not but I feel there should be a way to wrap the div without repeating the code

First I assigned a variable:

```
if block.settings.desktop!=blank
  assign link = true
  else
  assign link = false
  endif
```

Then I use the variable to wrap with an anchor:

```
 {% if link %}
    <a href="{{ block.settings.desktop }}" aria-label="{{ block.settings.desktop }}">
      <div class="hero-banner__content
                {{ banner_alignment }} {{ banner_alignment_mobile }}--
```

The question is

Comment: There's a lot of code and I don't see any click handlers anywhere to give a hint for what you're talking about. For those of us who aren't familiar with your code (i.e. everyone) maybe you can simplify the code to just the relevant bits or at least point out the specific lines of code you're talking about?

Comment: I edited the code and pointed out the place that I added my changes so you can see what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `if-else` to wrap anchor tag markup at the start and at the end.

So if you have `banner_link` `TRUE` it will add an anchor tag otherwise it will not.

```
{% if banner_link %}
  <a href="{{ block.settings.cta_link_desktop_1 }}" aria-label="{{ block.settings.cta_aria_desktop_1 }}">
{% endif %}

    // Your repeating code goes here single time :)
    <div class="hero-banner__content ....">
     ... 
    </div>

{% if banner_link %}
  </a>
{% endif %}
```

if any doubt please comment.